# I want to bundle a folder which does not have a starting point - Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

My app's folder structure is this:

```
- src-app
    - index.js
    - // other js code which i already bundle using webpack
- translations
    - en.josn
    - fr.json
```

I already create a bundle of src-app index.js (as entry point) and output it to ***public/public.js***.
Now I also want to bundle translation folder such as it outputs to ***public/translation/en.json***, fr.json etc.

I am using webpack 4.41.1

Comment: You just want to copy those translation files without change to the output directory…?

Comment: @deceze yes. You got me right. I just want to copy the translations folder and put it where my bundle (public.js) is kept already